# How to syntactically indicate a table for altering its column in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, heidisql, postgresql-14

I am trying to alter a table by changing the datatypes of a few columns from text to integer/boolean/date

When I try to execute it as

```
alter table "TimeSeriesData" alter COLUMN "details_id" TYPE BIGINT;
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  column "details_id" cannot be cast automatically to type bigintHINT:  You might need
to specify "USING "details_id"::bigint".uery
```

When I then tried to execute it as

```
alter table "TimeSeriesData" alter COLUMN "details_id" TYPE BIGINT USING (details_id::BIGINT);
```

I got the following error

```
ERROR:  column "details_id" does not existLINE 1: ... COLUMN "details_id" TYPE BIGINT USING 
(timeSeries...^HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "TimeSeriesData.details_id".uery
```

Finally tried it this way, as per suggestion from SQL GUI

```
alter table "TimeSeriesData" alter COLUMN "TimeSeriesData"."details_id" TYPE BIGINT 
USING (details_id::BIGINT);
```

Again, it led to this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."LINE 1: ...eriesData" alter COLUMN 
"TimeSeriesData"."details_...  ^uery
```

I am using TimescaleDB and heidiSQL as GUI for it.
Can you please help on how to proceed ahead

Comment: Also, I'd recommend checking if some data is not compatible with bigint. Example: 

`select * from timeseriesdata where details_id NOT SIMILAR TO '\d+'`;

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

- Create a new column.
- Migrate (cast) data to this column.
- Review data migration.
- Drop old column.
- Rename new column.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id Int PRIMARY KEY,
  my_bool VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, my_bool)
VALUES (1, '1');
INSERT INTO test (id, my_bool)
VALUES (2, '0');

ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN my_bool_2 int;

UPDATE test SET my_bool_2 = CAST(my_bool as int);
ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN my_bool;
ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN my_bool_2 TO my_bool;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a small example here, and I think you missed the `USING` clause.

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN value TYPE BIGINT USING value::BIGINT;
```

Here is the full example:

```sql
DROP TABLE my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table ( time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  value varchar);
SELECT create_hypertable('my_table', 'time');


INSERT INTO my_table (time, value) VALUES
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.01', '1012311'),
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.08',  '1022220'),
('2021-08-26 10:09:00.40',  '103333000');
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN value TYPE BIGINT USING value::BIGINT;
```

Then, check the results:

```sql
tsdb=> table my_table;
┌────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│          time          │   value   │
├────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.01 │   1012311 │
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.08 │   1022220 │
│ 2021-08-26 10:09:00.4  │ 103333000 │
└────────────────────────┴───────────┘
(3 rows)
```